# Got Py4JError when setting SparkContext

Tags: python, pyspark

When I tried to set up SparkContext with SparkConf, I ran into Py4JError.
My code is as follows:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Reference")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

And the error is like this:

```
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call `last)`
<ipython-input-5-313e7d9fd8ee> in <module>()
  1 from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
  2 conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Reference")
--> 3 sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
  4 #ref = sc.textFile("reference.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))
  5 #ref_res = ref.saveAsTextFile("ref.txt")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
--> 118                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    119         except:
    120             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    193         # data via a socket.
    194         # scala's mangled names w/ $ in them require special treatment.
--> 195         self._encryption_enabled = self._jvm.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled(self._jsc)
    196 
    197         self.pythonExec = os.environ.get("PYSPARK_PYTHON", 'python')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   1514         else:
   1515             raise Py4JError(
-> 1516                 "{0}.{1} does not exist in the JVM".format(self._fqn, name))
   1517 
   1518     def _get_args(self, args):

Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled does not exist in the JVM
```

Any help or advice please.

Comment: What spark version are you using?

Comment: Spark 2.3.2 and for java I use jdk1.8.0_192